# Pages don't seem to see my css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to this, and have created a Twitter Bootstrap page, based on an MVC4 application.

In my layout, I start with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" rel=""/>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Properties/../scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

And then the rest of the page.

Within my Site.css, which is where I put my custom css, I have the following:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.field-validation-error {
    color: #f00;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background-color: #fee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f00;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

.page-header {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.panel-body {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.featuredImg {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

It seems none of my pages are using this CSS though. The body doesn't seem to add the margin...

If I used Firebug, and select the CSS tab, I see no reference to Site.css. Only to 'bootstrap.min.css'.

In design time, the path to my CSS file seems right, as I can click it in the designer, and it takes me to the css file.

It just seems not to load it at runtime.

Is there a fault I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding rel to your link tag

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```